# Is it possible to use nodes of different type inside the Redshift cluster?

Tags: amazon-redshift

In our project, we have two distinctive classes of data that we want to store inside the Redshift cluster - one class of data requires a lot of space (terabytes), but we only run ad-hoc queries against it, so performance is not a big issue and another class of data is much smaller (tens of gigabytes), but we need to run significantly larger number of queries against it, so performance is an important factor. Given that distinction - first class of data is best suited for HDD-backed nodes, while second class is better on SSD-powered, more performance oriented nodes. We could separate this data potentially into two different clusters, but I wonder if it is possible to mix nodes of different type in the same cluster and somehow control which tables reside on which nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not mix two types of nodes together as of now.
I have same scenario like you have. So We also have two clusters one is ssd with less space, more queries but faster and other is non ssd which have tera bytes data which is used for historic report where query performance is not issue.

Comment: This is called the "hot" and "cold" pattern. Hot has more recent data, last week for example, and runs on SSD, and the Cold has all the data for the last 3 years and runs on Magnetic disks.